# Is it possible to remove records from an itemtype using Flexible search service?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to remove records from an itemtype using Flexible search service? As far as i know, Flexible search is only used for SELECT Operations.

Please suggest ways to remove records from an itemtype using a cron job? Thanks, Appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flexible search queries are not made to manipulate data ([source](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/FlexibleSearch)), if you want to delete data you could :

- Use the Model Service
- Run an impex file with the remove header ([source](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+Syntax#ImpExSyntax-HeaderMode))

Comment: for simple impex, you may also run it directly in hac/Console/ImpEx Import,
simply paste you impex in the textarea, and click on "Import Content"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use sql query as well to remove the data.

1. Go to HAC -> Console -> Flexible Search
2. Switch the tab to SQL Query
3. Execute SQL delete query (DELETE FROM table_name)
4. Make sure you run query in commit mode otherwise Hybris will rollback the changes.

[image]

Comment: It is not advisable to use SQL directly when working with Hybris. The table schemas are generated programmatically and do not always have useful foreign keys etc. Additionally, changes made directly with SQL will not be reflected in the Hybris cache layer and so Hybris may not notice that the data has changed for quite a while.

Comment: This is "SQL Query", NOT "Flexible Query", executing sql statement here equals to executing it in database DIRECTLY, it is NOT recommended.

Answer (score 1):

- You can create a Groovy script to delete all the records in a table using the modelService as mentioned aboved.
- Other option if you want to delete massively records from a table is to run an impex with the batchmode setted to true. ej:

  ```
  REMOVE StockLevel[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique = true]
                                   ;StockLevel
  ```

  Where the itemtype is the parameter that will be use to delete the table, you can change that parameter for the one that fills your needs of course.